# What's the grammar of "Me, Benjamin Clawhauser, ... stereotyping you"?

Tags: grammar, tense, sentence-structure, subjects

"Zootopia" around 00:14:04/01:48:32

> Benjamin Clawhauser: O.M. Goodness... They really did hire a bunny. *[Laughs]* What!? I gotta tell you, you are even cuter than I thought you'd be!
>
> Judy Hopps: Ooh, uh, you probably didn't know, but a bunny can call another bunny cute, but when other animals do it, it's a little...
>
> Benjamin Clawhauser: *[Gasps]* I am so sorry! **Me, Benjamin Clawhauser, the guy everyone thinks is just a flabby, donut-loving cop stereotyping you,** oh...

(http://zootopia.wikia.com/wiki/Zootopia/Transcript)

1 Why is the subject "me" instead of "I"?

2 Is the sentence in the past continuous tense? "Me *was* stereotyping you"? Why is "was" missing?

---

relative: [Why did Hopps the bunny use "didn't" when talking the present moment? Was it a kind of mood?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170456/why-did-hopps-the-bunny-use-didnt-when-talking-the-present-moment-was-it-a-k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a sort of conversational deletion.  The fuller version would be something like

> **Imagine** me stereotyping you

or

> **Here we see** me stereotyping you